# OpenLayers multi layer select

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map with multiple layers (A, B, C, D, E, F).
I need to be able to select items on different layers and interact with them.
Currently I can only select on F layer and the other layers are blocking me from selecting on B layer.

I create the layers...

```
var Fields = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
var Text = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
```

Add the layers to my map

```
map.addLayers([Text, ZipCode, Legal, Fields, FieldLabels]);
```

Call a highlight function I created as features are being added to the map...

```
    function HighLighText(ID) {
    //var mySelectStyle = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);
    //OpenLayers.Util.extend(mySelectStyle, { fillColor: "#f6b721", fillOpacity: 1 });

    mySelectStyle[ID] = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);
    OpenLayers.Util.extend(mySelectStyle, { fontColor: "#F6FF00", fillOpacity: .6 });
    mySelectStyle[ID].fontColor = "#F6FF00";
    mySelectStyle[ID].fillOpacity = .6;
    mySelectStyle[ID].label = String(ID);


    var txtReport = function (e) { OpenLayers.Console.log(e.type, e.feature.id); };
    highlightTextCtrl[ID] = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(Fields[ID], {
        hover: true,
        highlightOnly: true,
        renderIntent: "temporary",
        selectStyle: mySelectStyle[ID]


    });



    map.addControl(highlightTextCtrl[ID]);    
    highlightTextCtrl[ID].activate();

};
```

The above function works great as long as I hide the layers above it...how can I make this work without having to hide layers?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Are you talking about something like this? view-source:http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html I working example would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnBarca Yes, except that when I add an array of layers to my  Select feature then it doesn't work at all...I'd like to provide I working example but I don't know that it will be possible.  I do appreciate any help you can give though.

Comment: @JohnBarça For instance in the above code that works...if I add the layers like this...map.addLayers([Fields, FieldLabelsText, ZipCode, Legal]); now Zipcode and legal are blocking me from hovering or selecting Fields.